# How to create radio button by String

Tags: vb.net, string, radio-button

How to create radio button by String in VB.net ?

I must to create 1 table include multiple radio button.

My code

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim str As String = "<table><tr><td><asp:radiobutton ID='Radiobutton" & i & "' runat='server' Text='" & i & "' /></td></tr></table>"
Response.Write(str)
```

Note: I must use radio button control .Net

Comment: better use `asp:literal` control for this

Comment: @Usman I have used "asp:literal" but it not working.

Comment: @Usman this is my code on page.aspx  
<asp:Literal id="Literal1" Text="" runat="server" />
this is code page.aspx.vb  
Dim str As String = "<asp:radiobutton ID='Radiobutton" & i & "' runat='server' name='price' Text='" & i & "' GroupName='price' AutoPostBack='True'></asp:radiobutton>"
Literal1.Text = str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use RadioButton that way since it's a server control. You have to write pure html on the response:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim str As String = "<table><tr><td><input id='Radiobutton' type='radio' name='Radiobutton' value='" & i & "' />" & i & "</td></tr></table>"
Response.Write(str)
```

Or you have to use HtmlGenericControl without writing directly on Response:

```
Dim table as New HtmlGenericControl("table");
Dim tr as New HtmlGenericControl("tr");
Dim td as New HtmlGenericControl("td");
Dim radio as New RadioButton();
table.Controls.Add(tr);
tr.Controls.Add(td);
td.Controls.Add(radio);

Page.Controls.Add(table);
```